# Executable as OSGi bundle with parameter exchange

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, osgi, exe

I have a particular executable that I would like to integrate in my Eclipse RCP Framework. Is it possible to wrap the exe in a bundle, define the startingpoints and parameters and start it as a separate tool from my framework? The other question refers to the other way round. Can I retrieve returnvalues from an executable bundle or even exchange parameters/values/something on the fly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any existing framework which does that but you can run the executable with [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) or [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) in a custom bundle which registers it as service. It obviusly needs some coding and it will be platform dependent, `exe` files runs on Windows.

This question also could help: [Including additional resources with OSGi bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411812/including-additional-resources-with-osgi-bundles)